# Upcasting helper method?

Tags: c#, casting

I have the following classes:

```
class Alpha
{
}
class Beta : Alpha
{
}
class Gamma : Beta
{
}
class Epsilon : Beta
{
}
```

And I have a couple methods where I take them as parameters:

```
void Receiver(Gamma gamma);
void Receiver(Epsilon epsilon);
void Receiver(Beta beta);
void Receiver(Alpha alpha);
```

I require something a bit unusual here.
I want to be able to pass Alpha objects to all methods, but I don't want methods like `void Receiver(Beta beta);` being able to receive objects of types that inherit from `Beta` (that is, I want to, at worst, raise an `Exception` if a `Gamma` or `Epsilon` object is passed.

How can I best implement this in such a way that is generic enough?

I was thinking for the first part, I should have a method that allows for upcasting, such as

```
class Alpha
{
    public T Upcast<T>() where T : Alpha
    {
        // somehow return a T
    }
}
```

The issues here are that I want this to work on all levels, for instance I want being able to "upcast" `Beta` too.

The second part should be easier, as I would just throw on objects being passed that are above the type I require.

so something like this should suffice:

```
void Receiver(Epsilon epsilon)
{
    // if epsilon inherits from Epsilon, throw.
}
```

Can you help me with the first part of my problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a method that accepts a `Base` as a parameter and will not work with a `Derived`, your class design is wrong. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: This is for a special case where I use reflection to parse properties into query string parameters, I don't want to accept derived classes since those may contain properties whose properties would result in illegal query string parameters in the pertaining API call.

Comment: I take your point though that maybe everything should be `sealed`, but still, what matters to me is the upcasting method.

Comment: Then simply write code that filters param/value properties based on a whitelist that depends on which API you intend to call and run it as part of the "call API with these parameters" method.

Comment: I'm trying to allow as little user error as possible here, that's why I don't provide the whole list and then filter myself.

Comment: Then throw an exception if you find parameters not in the whitelist. You were going to throw one anyway, and this solution also covers the case where you e.g. add a property to `Beta` and forget that your query will barf on it. My point is that *you are fixating on the wrong approach*, and with that I let's leave this subject to rest. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be struggling with code that can deal with a *given* type, but it cannot be trusted to deal properly with subtypes. This is generally speaking a violation of many OOP principles, one of them being LSP, or [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

You might be in a place where you could consider the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) as a means of overcoming this problem. It's very close to what you already have, with some minor modification, which is good! It's nice when patterns emerge from your code, rather than being forced upon it.

Your `void Receiver` methods are essentially already visitor implementations, so let's rename them and create an interface.

```
interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(Gamma gamma);
    void Visit(Epsilon epsilon);
    void Visit(Beta beta);
    void Visit(Alpha alpha);
}
```

Your class that is handling the processing of each element type simply needs to implement that interface.

```
class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Gamma gamma) { Console.WriteLine("Visiting Gamma object"); }
    public void Visit(Epsilon epsilon) { Console.WriteLine("Visiting Epsilon object"); }
    public void Visit(Beta beta) { Console.WriteLine("Visiting Beta object"); }
    public void Visit(Alpha alpha) { Console.WriteLine("Visiting Alpha object"); }
}
```

Then have each element type also implement a simple and common interface

```
interface IElement { void Accept(IVisitor visitor); }

class Alpha : IElement 
{
    public virtual void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
} 

class Beta : Alpha 
{
    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

// etc.
```

(Strictly speaking, the interfaces aren't *necessary*, it's just good form.)

And there you go, a method of double dispatch where an element invokes a visitor method *specific to its own type*, even though you might have a reference to it via a base type.

```
Alpha alpha = new Beta();
IVisitor visitor = new Visitor();
alpha.Accept(visitor);
```

If you have implemented it properly, you should see "Visiting Beta object" on the screen (or, in your terms, you should see the desired "Receiver" behavior executed.)

---

Another option you might consider is simply making `Receiver` a virtual method on your base class and let the derived classes override it, and have the behaviors inside the classes, if that makes sense for your hierarchy. If the behaviors need to be external, you could also consider a factory approach that knows how to create a specific processor for a given class. There are many options you have that do not involve your program going nuts if a subtype is passed to a method expecting the base.

---

> I require something a bit unusual here.  I want to be able to pass
>   Alpha objects to all methods, but I don't want methods like void
>   Receiver(Beta beta); being able to receive objects of types that
>   inherit from Beta (that is, I want to, at worst, raise an Exception if
>   a Gamma or Epsilon object is passed.

This is very strange indeed. And I'm not sure you actually want that. You seem to have the inheritance hierarchy flipped on its head, where super types can be substituted for derived types and not the other way around, and you should *really* rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a GetType and check that its a beta.

Comment: I want to upcast it, not make sure it's of the derived type.

Comment: Make a new beta from an epsilon ?

Comment: Make a new `Epsilon` from a `Beta`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to pass Alpha objects to all methods

You can't do that reliably.  Alpha is not a Gamma, so you can't reliably use it as a parameter to Receiver(Gamma).  Otherwise you could do this:

```
Alpha a = new Gamma(); // legal
Receiver((Epsilon)a);    // not legal
```

If you define the Receiver functions as you did in your question, the compiler will choose the right method based on the declared type (or casted type if you cast it):

```
Epsilon e = new Epsilon();
Alpha a = new Gamma();

Receiver(e);         // calls Receiver(Epsilon)
Receiver(a);         // calls Receiver(Alpha)
Receiver((Gamma)a);  // calls Receiver(Gamma)
Receiver((Beta)e);   // calls Receiver(Beta)
```

So the compiler will choose the proper method if you call it properly.

> but I don't want methods like `void Receiver(Beta beta);` being able to receive objects of types that inherit from Beta

Then you're not using inheritance properly.  `Gamma` *is a* `Beta`.  Why do you want to prevent inherited types from using the method?  If you want Gamma and Beta to share some properties/methods without inheritance then choose another pattern such as **Encapsulation** or **Composition** and use interfaces.

That said, your Upcast function should be simple:

```
public T Upcast<T>() where T : Alpha
{
    return this as T;  // will return null is this is not a T
}

...

new Beta().Upcast<Gamma>();  // will return null
new Epsilon().Upcate<Epsilon>();  // will return the Epsilon
```