# Is there a way of strictly enforce the type that can be used. (Very Explict Casting)

Tags: .net, types, type-coercion

Is there a way of "strictly" con-straining or enforcing the type that can be use.

```
S <: T
```

Something like

```
Method( value As T ) ' Any Type of T including subtypes of T  
Method( value Is T ) ' Only take a T not a subtype of T
```

I can do this at runtime

```
 If TypeOf value Is T Then
```

But this is a runtime check, compile-time checking would be more preferable

```
Option Strict On
```

This only restricts it to (implicit) Type Widening Coerecions.

I would like were all Type Coerecions have to be Explicit.

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: What are you doing where a subtype cannot be a valid substitution for a base type (generally violating [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))? Your scenario might lend itself towards a pattern such as [Visitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828857/upcasting-helper-method/8830079#8830079).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
private void Method<T>(T mytype) where T: MyClass
{
}
```

That is possible solution

Comment: Still allows subclasses of `MyClass` to be passed in.

Comment: yes and that is the answer for your 1st part question. You can read more about constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, as a *user* of a type - you have no say in whether you will accept derived types. If you are the *owner* of a type, then you can not allow derived types by marking your class as `sealed`.

That being said, your request goes against a number of OOD principles. You may want to rethink your design if this is actually necessary.